# error in line 26" [Error] 'Top' was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

class node
{ 
public: 
    int ID;
    string name;
    float price;
    int Quantity;
    node *next;

};

node*top;

boolisempty ()
{ 
    return top==NULL;
}

void push (string N,int I,float P,int Q)
{
    node *p=new node ();

    p->ID=I;
    p->name=N;
    p->Quantity=Q;
    p->price=P;
    p->next=Top;
    Top=P;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `top`?

Comment: I got another error in line 27

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 27 5 E:\A\main.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'float' to 'node*' in assignment

Comment: I don't understand; are those methods supposed to be part of that class?

Comment: @AbdullahMustafa `top` is a node*, you're writing `top = P`, P is a float.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. I can't understand what you intend for any of this code to do. Simply telling us that you got an error isn't helpful, because fixing compiler errors does not make the code correct, and because the purpose isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to the site

Comment: BTW, `N`, `I`, `P`, `Q` are not descriptive variable names. Always avoid using ambiguous names for functions and variables and classes and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Top`, not `top`.

```
void push (string N,int I,float P,int Q)
{
    node *p=new node ();

    p->ID=I;
    p->name=N;
    p->Quantity=Q;
    p->price=P;
    p->next=top;
    top=P;
}
```